# Image not found before angular has updated document

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular JS application, which has a number of images, from an array.

My model looks something like this

```
$scope.images = [ {url: 'someimage.png', desc: 'some desc'}, {url: 'someimage.png', desc: 'some desc'} ]
```

In my view, I iterate over this, to display all the images.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="image in images" ><img src="{{image.url}}" /></li>
</ul>
```

This works, but I get some page errors, which say

```
404 Not Found - http://localhost/{{image.url}}
```

The images are displaying correctly, so it is clearly the images are trying to be loaded before Angular has parsed to document get it ready. My scripts are also in the head, so it should not be a javascript ordering error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem here was that I should be using `ng-src` and not `src`, so that it will only try to display the image when Angular is ready.

So, the correct code looks like

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="image in images" ><img ng-src="{{image.url}}" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I love angular so much.

Comment: This saved my day.

Comment: when iterating large set of data, some images get loaded and some images are not getting loaded using ng-src & passing image url. I guess it is due to asynchronous behaviour of JS. So is there any solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you, its very helpful.. Solved my problem too